# MySQL Crystal query, how do I select CurrentDate() field and blank dates?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I'm new to SQL. I'm trying to select records less than the current date which is working however we also have entries where the date field is blank which I need to include in the report. I need to be able to see both the current date AND dates that are blank. Any way to accomplish this?

{LOAN1.XLN-PROMDATE} <  CurrentDate()

Comment: Date field blank means you dont have any value for date in database

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax in crystal would be `isnull ({datefield}) or {date field} < {?parameter}` isnull is not comparable to a value - null means the absence of data, which is not comparable. Hope that helps